# Вернуть строку с дублированными символами python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана строка. Вернуть новую строку, где будет дублироваться каждый символ первоначальной строки.

```
def double_char(string):
    print(string.join(string))
```

Не понимаю, нужно нарезать строку в вставить между каждым символом, скопированный символ...или как еще?

```
 def double_char(string):
     print(string.join(string))
```

В этой функции результат другой получается.

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join([ch*2 for ch in string])
```

Здесь идёт итерация строки по символам (каждый из которых есть строка длины 1), при этом каждый символ удваивается, потом происходит непосредственное соединение полученных строк (каждая из которых имеет длину 2):

```
string = 'abc1'
''.join([ch*2 for ch in string])  # 'aabbcc11'
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсивное решение:

```py
def double_char(string: str) -> str:
    if len(string) == 1:
        return string * 2
    return double_char(string[0]) + double_char(string[1:])


print(double_char('Spam!'))
```

Аналогичная `lambda`:

```py
(lambda f: lambda arg1: f(f, arg1))(lambda f, string: (string * 2) if len(string) == 1 else (f(f, string[0]) + f(f, string[1:])))
```

*stdout:*

```html
SSppaamm!!
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все варианты решения получились :) хотя наверное это не все ещё